# Embedded Signing Finish Later Button

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the embedded signing view, and when a client clicks on the Finish Later button they never receive an email.. in the docusign website I have set this to send it out in 1 day... I am also setting the name and email address in the request for the embedded signing.. Not sure what I am missing here.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What type of email notification are you expecting when your client clicks the Finish Later button?  Are you referring to the Envelope Reminders feature, which has nothing to do with Finish Later??

Comment: Yes I was hoping the reminders was tied to the finish later button. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of account-level settings related to controlling the email notifications that a captive/embedded recipient will receive automatically from DocuSign.  I don't know whether or not these settings affect the "Reminder" email notification for embedded/captive recipients, but it might be worth investigating:

[image]

Generally speaking, the *"captive/embedded recipient"* scenario is designed such that your application will be responsible for communicating with the signer (i.e., by default, DocuSign will ***not*** automatically send email notifications to embededded/captive signers, except in cases where the email notification settings above have been set to override this default behavior).  So, I wouldn't be surprised if the "Reminder" notification email isn't supported for use with an embedded/captive recipient.

*(Added another screenshot -- settings on the **Preferences >> Features** page):*

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing those options anywhere.. I do have under Account Administration - > features -> email notifications, a default setting for new user when "they are added to ..." then under that is says notify me when" I am a signer: "I have an envelope to sign.

Comment: You should see these settings on the PREFERENCES >> FEATURES page -- try searching that page for the word 'embedded', and you should find them -- located not to far above the "Email Notifications" link that you mention.  (I've updated my answer with a broader screenshot of these settings on the "Features" page.)

Comment: Yes it helped to find it with the expanded screen... it was checked to suppress and I unchecked it, di a test and still no emails... any other suggestions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, no other suggestions.  As I said before, I wouldn't be surprised if the "Reminder" notification email isn't supported for use with an embedded/captive recipient, since that scenario is designed such that your application handles the communication with the recipient (rather than DocuSign emailing the recipient).